# Unable to add image in footer section of PDF using itextsharp library

Tags: asp.net, pdf, itext, footer, document

Using library iTextSharp 5.5.13.3 version in my dotnet Widnows application 4.7.2, not able to insert an image inside footer in my pdf document, please help. some code i have tried from internet it doesn't display footer image at all, however i am able to insert image in header and it displays fine.

Please find below code i used for header image

```
 protected internal class MyEventHandler : PdfPageEventHelper
 {
     protected Image img;
     protected string HeaderCenter;
     protected string HeaderRight;
     protected string FooterLeft;
     protected string FooterRight;

     public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
     {
         var contentStream = writer.DirectContent;
         PdfDocument pdfDoc = contentStream.PdfDocument;
         Rectangle pageSize = document.PageSize;

         float LeftX = 10;
         float CenterX = pageSize.Width / 2;
         float RigthX = pageSize.Width - 10;

         float HeaderY = pageSize.Height - 30;
         float FooterY = 10;

         string baseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

         string fullpath = Path.Combine(baseDir, "world-image.jpg");

         img = Image.GetInstance(fullpath);

         if (img != null)
         {
             img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
             img.ScaleAbsolute(840, 40);

             var headerImageTemplate = contentStream.CreateTemplate(img.Width, img.Height);
             headerImageTemplate.AddImage(img);
             
             contentStream.AddTemplate(headerImageTemplate, 0, HeaderY - 20);
         }
        
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HeaderCenter))
         {
             var p = new Phrase(HeaderCenter, new Font(_enclosing._baseFontRegular, FONT_SIZE));
             ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(contentStream, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, p, CenterX, HeaderY, 0, PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL, ColumnText.AR_LIG);
         }

         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HeaderRight))
         {
             contentStream.BeginText();
             contentStream.SetFontAndSize(_enclosing._baseFontRegular, FONT_SIZE);
             contentStream.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, HeaderRight, RigthX, HeaderY, 0);
             contentStream.EndText();
         }

         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FooterLeft))
         {
             var p = new Phrase(FooterLeft, new Font(_enclosing._baseFontRegular, FONT_SIZE));
             ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(contentStream, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, p, LeftX, FooterY, 0, PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL, ColumnText.AR_LIG);

         }

         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FooterRight))
         {
             var rect = new Rectangle(pageSize.Right - 240, 0, pageSize.Right - 5, 60);
             ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(contentStream);
             ct.SetSimpleColumn(rect);
             ct.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
             ct.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
             ct.AddElement(new Paragraph(FooterRight));
             ct.Go();
         }

     }

     internal MyEventHandler(ITextPDFSharpHelper _enclosing)
     {
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_enclosing._pageHeader.left))
         {

             var imageStr = _enclosing._pageHeader.left;
             img = Image.GetInstance(imageStr);

         }
         HeaderCenter = _enclosing._pageHeader.center;
         HeaderRight = _enclosing._pageHeader.right;
         FooterLeft = _enclosing._pageFooter.left;
         FooterRight = _enclosing._pageFooter.right;

         this._enclosing = _enclosing;

     }
     private readonly ITextPDFSharpHelper _enclosing;
 }
```

i am using MyEventHandler  class to insert image in header, same way i tried for footer, but it is not displaying

Please help..